# Send a ping to each IP on a subnet

Tags: networking, shell, ping, arp

Is there a command line based way to send pings to each computer in a subnet?
Like

```
for(int i = 1; i < 254; i++)
    ping(192.168.1.i);
```

to enforce arp resolution?

Comment: Check if [this blog post](http://nomius.blogspot.com/2006/06/checking-network-with-bash.html) has what you need.

Comment: `for i in $(seq 1 254); do ping -c1 -t 1 192.168.11.$i; done` - its Native, without third party tools.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I would suggest the use of **fping** with the mask option, since you are not restricting yourself in ping.

```
fping -g 192.168.1.0/24
```

The response will be easy to parse in a script:

```
192.168.1.1 is alive
192.168.1.2 is alive
192.168.1.3 is alive
192.168.1.5 is alive
...
192.168.1.4 is unreachable
192.168.1.6 is unreachable
192.168.1.7 is unreachable
...
```

Note: Using the argument `-a` will restrict the output to reachable ip addresses, you may want to use it otherwise fping will also print unreachable addresses:

```
fping -a -g 192.168.1.0/24
```

From man:

> **fping** differs from **ping** in that you can specify any number of targets
>   on the command line, or specify a file containing the lists of targets
>   to ping. Instead of sending to one target until it times out or
>   replies, **fping** will send out a ping packet and move on to the next
>   target in a round-robin fashion.

More info: http://fping.org/

Comment: As well fping is way lighter than nmap

Comment: Use `-aq` if you only want to see the list of reachable addresses, and not individual ping results.

Answer (score 129):

Not all machines have `nmap` available, but it's a wonderful tool for any network discovery, and certainly better than iterating through independent `ping` commands.

```
$ nmap -n -sP 10.0.0.0/24

Starting Nmap 4.20 ( http://insecure.org ) at 2009-02-02 07:41 CST
Host 10.0.0.1 appears to be up.
Host 10.0.0.10 appears to be up.
Host 10.0.0.104 appears to be up.
Host 10.0.0.124 appears to be up.
Host 10.0.0.125 appears to be up.
Host 10.0.0.129 appears to be up.
Nmap finished: 256 IP addresses (6 hosts up) scanned in 2.365 seconds
```

Comment: Best answer to date because it is the first to be compatible with the reality that not all subnets are the same size, and using the /24 notation can be generalized to any size subnet.

Comment: The nmap it's not available in all machines/servers while the ping it's. That small issue make this option not to be the best answer. But if both tools are present this can be the chosen one.

Comment: This command may lost some hosts, but these can be `ping`, why?

Comment: Could be just `nmap -sn 10.0.0.0/24`? There'll be no DNS lookup (`-n`) and [from nmap manual](https://nmap.org/book/man-host-discovery.html) _In previous releases of Nmap, -sn was known as -sP._.
@Honghe.Wu some hosts are configured to no answer pings.

Comment: This is much faster than ping

Answer (score 49):

**Broadcast ping:**

```
$ ping 192.168.1.255
PING 192.168.1.255 (192.168.1.255): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.1.154: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.104 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.51: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=2.058 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 192.168.1.151: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=2.135 ms (DUP!)
...
```

(Add a `-b` option on Linux)

Comment: note: you may need to add a "-b" in there depending on version/platform

Comment: Also, not all operating systems will respond to a broadcast ping (by default).

Answer (score 20):

I just came around this question, but the answers did not satisfy me.
So i rolled my own:

```
echo $(seq 254) | xargs -P255 -I% -d" " ping -W 1 -c 1 192.168.0.% | grep -E "[0-1].*?:"
```

- Advantage 1: You don't need to install any additional tool
- Advantage 2: It's fast. It does everything in Parallel with a timout for every ping of 1s ("`-W 1`"). So it will finish in 1s :)
- Advantage 3: The output is like this

> ```
> 64 bytes from 192.168.0.16: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.019 ms
> 64 bytes from 192.168.0.12: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.78 ms
> 64 bytes from 192.168.0.21: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=2.43 ms
> 64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.97 ms
> 64 bytes from 192.168.0.11: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=619 ms
> ```

Edit:
And here is the same as script, for when your xargs do not have the -P flag, as is the case in openwrt (i just found out)

```
for i in $(seq 255);
do
 ping -W 1 -c 1 10.0.0.$i | grep 'from' &
done
```

Answer (score 18):

In Bash shell:

```
#!/bin/sh

COUNTER=1

while [ $COUNTER -lt 254 ]
do
   ping 192.168.1.$COUNTER -c 1
   COUNTER=$(( $COUNTER + 1 ))
done
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be `$COUNTER -lt 255` to test `192.168.1.254`?

Answer (score 10):

The command line utility nmap can do this too:

```
nmap -sP 192.168.1.*
```

Comment: You'll want to put the parameter in quotes.

Answer (score 7):

```
for i in $(seq 1 254); do ping -c1 -t 1 192.168.11.$i; done
```

Adding a `-t 1` waits only one second before exiting. This improves the speed a lot if you just have a few devices connected to that subnet.

Comment: Excellent. 1) Its Native 2) i do not have to install all those crap tools in Arduino.

Comment: I also love its use of bare tools found on limited systems too. For *OpenWRT* users, keep in mind that `-t` parameter becomes `-w` for `ping`.

Answer (score 6):

```
FOR /L %i in (1,1,254) DO PING 192.168.1.%i -n 1 -w 100 | for /f "tokens=3 delims=: " %j in ('find /i "TTL="') do echo %j>>IPsOnline.txt
```

Comment: Which shell does have uppercase `FOR` and this weird syntax? I think marginal technologies have to be explicitly noted.

Answer (score 6):

This is a modification of @david-rodríguez-dribeas answer above, which runs all the pings in parallel (much faster) and only shows the output for ip addresses which return the ping.

```
export COUNTER=1
while [ $COUNTER -lt 255 ]
do
    ping $1$COUNTER -c 1 -w 400 | grep -B 1 "Lost = 0" &
    COUNTER=$(( $COUNTER + 1 ))
done
```

Answer (score 3):

Under linux, I think ping -b 192.168.1.255 will work (192.168.1.255 is the broadcast address for 192.168.1.*) however IIRC that doesn't work under windows.

Answer (score 1):

I came late but here is a little script I made for this purpose that I run in Windows PowerShell. You should be able to copy and paste it into the ISE. This will then run the arp command and save the results into a .txt file and open it in notepad.

```
# Declare Variables
$MyIpAddress
$MyIpAddressLast

# Declare Variable And Get User Inputs
$IpFirstThree=Read-Host 'What is the first three octects of you IP addresses please include the last period?'
$IpStart=Read-Host 'Which IP Address do you want to start with? Include NO periods.'
$IpEnd=Read-Host 'Which IP Address do you want to end with? Include NO periods.'
$SaveMyFilePath=Read-Host 'Enter the file path and name you want for the text file results.'
$PingTries=Read-Host 'Enter the number of times you want to try pinging each address.'

#Run from start ip and ping
#Run the arp -a and output the results to a text file
#Then launch notepad and open the results file
Foreach($MyIpAddressLast in $IpStart..$IpEnd)
{$MyIpAddress=$IpFirstThree+$MyIpAddressLast
    Test-Connection -computername $MyIpAddress -Count $PingTries}
arp -a | Out-File $SaveMyFilePath
notepad.exe $SaveMyFilePath
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh

COUNTER=$1

while [ $COUNTER -lt 254 ]
do
 echo $COUNTER
 ping -c 1 192.168.1.$COUNTER | grep 'ms'
 COUNTER=$(( $COUNTER + 1 ))
done

#specify start number like this: ./ping.sh 1
#then run another few instances to cover more ground
#aka one at 1, another at 100, another at 200
#this just finds addresses quicker. will only print ttl info when an address resolves
```

Answer (score 0):

This Script works well in **OpenWRT**

In a new file put this code ,

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Online IPs" > out.txt
COUNTER=1

while [ $COUNTER -lt 255 ]
do
 ping $1.$COUNTER -c 1 -w 400 | grep "time" >> out.txt &
 COUNTER=$(( $COUNTER + 1 ))
done
killall ping
```

Set execution permision and launch it

root@r1:/# **nping 192.168.1**

then view all host connected in out.txt file

Answer (score 0):

To ping all IPs in subnet, use this command in Terminal (pre-install nmap, if needed with brew install nmap):

```
sudo nmap -sn -PE 192.168.N.0/24
```

where 192.168.N.0/24,
is must set up of N - where u put ur number between 0 'n 255,
if you have IP in subnet like 192.168.110.20 -> use this:

```
sudo nmap -sn -PE 192.168.110.0/24
```

Answer (score 0):

On macOS I use a bash one line command like this which is super fast:

```
for i in $(seq 254); do { ping -W 100 -c 1 -n 192.168.0.$i | grep "bytes from" & }; done
```

as `xargs` didn't work as expected (-d is not supported by macOS xargs). I also added -n to ping to not lookup the DNS name (saves time). The -W 100 was necessary to give my devices enough time to respond to the ping.

Answer (score -3):

```
for i in $(seq 1 254); do ping -c1 192.168.11.$i; done
```

Comment: I guess this answer was downvoted because it is lacking any explanation? ...or because it would take 42 minutes (standard ping in Ubuntu, worst case) to complete?