# Ping all addresses in network, windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Is it possible in windows cmd line to check all of the network addresses (with ping or similar) to see which ones are taken/ have active devices:

ie. something that does something like the following:

```
for i = 0 to 255
    ping 192.168.1.i //Print this
end
```

This is psuedo code obviously. I am wondering if it is possible to do something like this in windows cmd. It would be great if you didn't need a batch file, but i understand if this is impossible.

PS. Also please mention if there is a program to do this, but it would be nice to do it in cmd.

Comment: I have no knoledge, just wondering... would `ping 192.168.1.255` get responses from all the devices in the subnet?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Open the Command Prompt and type in the following:

```
FOR /L %i IN (1,1,254) DO ping -n 1 192.168.10.%i | FIND /i "Reply">>c:\ipaddresses.txt
```

Change 192.168.10 to match you own network.

By using -n 1 you are asking for only 1 packet to be sent to each computer instead of the usual 4 packets.

The above command will ping all IP Addresses on the 192.168.10.0 network and create a text document in the C:\ drive called ipaddresses.txt.Â  This text document should only contain IP Addresses that replied to the ping request.

Although it will take quite a bit longer to complete, you can also resolve the IP Addresses to HOST names by simply adding -a to the ping command.

```
FOR /L %i IN (1,1,254) DO ping -a -n 1 192.168.10.%i | FIND /i "Reply">>c:\ipaddresses.txt
```

This is from [Here](http://www.itresource.com.au/2008/04/11/find-all-activeused-ip-addresses-on-your-network/)

Comment: Great answer, however, it currently prints out that the find parameter is not correct. How can I fix that?

Comment: Try to paste the command in a text editor and delete and re-add the quotes. The quotes you copy are some HTML encoded double quote.

Comment: I've edited the post to fix the smart quotes.  Should work now. :-)

Comment: This command appears to cause the command prompt to crash on Windows 8.

Comment: be aware that depending on your windows configuration c:\ipaddresses.txt might not be writeable for a none Admin user, change the path to a folder that is writeable to the current user

Comment: To increase the speed of this script running, add the -w parameter to set a relatively low timeout to wait for each reply. On my fast, local network I set this to 10 and it cut the time to run the script in less than half.

Comment: If using this in a batch file, one should use `%%i` instead of `%i`.

Comment: On a German language windows installation, use "Antwort" instead of "Reply":

`FOR /L %i IN (1,1,254) DO ping -a -n 1 192.168.10.%i | FIND /i "Antwort">>d:\ipaddresses.txt`

Comment: The problem with this is it is not consistent - it misses alive devices.

Answer (score 42):

I know this is a late response, but a neat way of doing this is to ping the broadcast address which populates your local arp cache.

This can then be shown by running arp -a which will list all the addresses in you local arp table.

```
ping 192.168.1.255
arp -a
```

Hopefully this is a nice neat option that people can use.

Comment: on my setup `ping 192.168.1.255; arp -a` alone did not show the dynamic ip but: `0..255 | ForEach-Object {ping 192.168.1.$_}` followed by `arp -a` did (powershell).

Comment: Note that not all devices reply to ping on the broadcast address

Comment: Note that in a network with VLANs this will not work as you only ARP for devices in your local subnet.

Comment: Sometimes the admins/users on the target machine(s) may configure to ignore ping requests, i.e. don't send ping replies. Then what can you propose to identify those existed devices, but not identified using `ping`?

Comment: @daniel.kahlenberg 0..255 | ForEach-Object {ping -n 1 -w 1 192.168.1.$_} does the same but much faster (only one ping for each host with a 1 ms timeout).

Answer (score 21):

Best Utility in terms of speed is **Nmap**.

write @ cmd prompt:

> Nmap -sn -oG ip.txt 192.168.1.1-255

this will just ping all the ip addresses in the range given and store it in simple text file

It takes just **2** secs to scan **255** hosts using Nmap.

Comment: On my machine it took slightly longer than 2 seconds (maybe 10?); however, the batch file above takes about ten minutes, and I needed to run a lot of range searches, so this was the best route for me.

Answer (score 13):

Provided the windows box is in the same subnet:

```
for /L %a in (1,1,254) do start ping 192.168.0.%a
```

This will complete in less than 15 seconds and

```
arp -a
```

will return any alive host.

Fastest native way I know of in Windows.

Comment: even faster: `for /L %a in (1,1,254) do @start /b ping 146.254.179.%a -w 100 -n 2 >nul`. And you should `arp -d` before to delete any old entries to get just alive hosts.

Comment: @Stephan But that also changes the output order to not be sequential.

Comment: @NetMage it doesn't have to be sequential - it's just to fill the `arp` database, which displays its entries sequentially anyway.

Comment: @Stephan I see what you mean - that doesn't work for me I am on a heavy VLAN network :)

Answer (score 5):

This post asks the same question, but for linux - you may find it helpful.  [Send a ping to each IP on a subnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503171/send-a-ping-to-each-ip-on-a-subnet)

nmap is probably the best tool to use, as it can help identify host OS as well as being faster.  It is available for the windows platform on the nmap.org site

Comment: Yeah, I have done it in Linux plenty of times, but not in windows.

Answer (score 2):

All you are wanting to do is to see if computers are connected to the network and to gather their IP addresses. You can utilize angryIP scanner: http://angryip.org/ to see what IP addresses are in use on a particular subnet or groups of subnets.

I have found this tool very helpful when trying to see what IPs are being used that are not located inside of my DHCP.

Comment: The link you provided is giving a 404. http://www.angryip.org works fine though, the subpaths  are not needed

Answer (score 2):

An expansion and useful addition to egmackenzie's "arp -a" solution for Windows -

**Windows Example searching for my iPhone on the WiFi network**

(pre: iPhone WiFi disabled)

- [Open Command Prompt in Admin mode](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-run-command-prompt-as-an-administrator) (R.C. Start & look in menu)
- arp -d                   <- clear the arp listing!
- ping 10.1.10.255         <- take your subnet, and ping '255', everyone
- arp -a
- iPhone WiFi on
- ping 10.1.10.255
- arp -a

See below for example:

[image]

Here is a nice writeup on the use of 'arp -d' here if interested -

- [TechRepublic - Quick Tips Flush the ARP cache in Windows 7](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/quick-tips-flush-the-arp-cache-in-windows-7/)

Answer (score 1):

Some things seem appeared to have changed in batch scripts on Windows 8, and the solution above by DGG now causes the Command Prompt to crash.

The following solution worked for me:

```
@echo off
set /a n=0
:repeat
set /a n+=1
echo 192.168.1.%n%
ping -n 1 -w 500 192.168.1.%n% | FIND /i "Reply">>ipaddresses.txt
if %n% lss 254 goto repeat
type ipaddresses.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

[aping](https://www.iea-software.com/aping) can provide a list of hosts and whether each has responded to pings.

```
 aping -show all 192.168.1.*
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF

IF "%SUBNET%"=="" SET SUBNET=10

:ARGUMENTS
ECHO SUBNET=%SUBNET%
ECHO ARGUMENT %1 
IF "%1"=="SUM" GOTO SUM
IF "%1"=="SLOW" GOTO SLOW
IF "%1"=="ARP" GOTO ARP
IF "%1"=="FAST" GOTO FAST

REM PRINT ARP TABLE BY DEFAULT
:DEFAULT
ARP -a
GOTO END

REM METHOD 1 ADDRESS AT A TIME
:SLOW
ECHO START SCAN
ECHO %0 > ipaddresses.txt
DATE /T >> ipaddresses.txt
TIME /T >> ipaddresses.txt
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,254) DO ping -a -n 2 192.168.%SUBNET%.%%i | FIND /i "TTL="  >> ipaddresses.txt
GOTO END

REM METHOD 2 MULTITASKING ALL ADDRESS AT SAME TIME
:FAST
ECHO START FAST SCANNING 192.168.%SUBNET%.X
set /a n=0
:FASTLOOP
set /a n+=1
ECHO 192.168.%SUBNET%.%n%
START CMD.exe /c call ipaddress.bat 192.168.%SUBNET%.%n% 
IF %n% lss 254 GOTO FASTLOOP
GOTO END

:SUM
ECHO START SUM
ECHO %0 > ipaddresses.txt
DATE /T >> ipaddresses.txt
TIME /T >> ipaddresses.txt
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,254) DO TYPE ip192.168.%SUBNET%.%%i.txt | FIND /i "TTL=" >> ipaddresses.txt
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,254) DO DEL ip192.168.%SUBNET%.%%i.txt
type ipaddresses.txt
GOTO END

:ARP
ARP -a >> ipaddresses.txt
type ipaddresses.txt
GOTO END


:END
ECHO DONE WITH IP SCANNING
ECHO OPTION "%0 SLOW" FOR SCANNING 1 AT A TIME
ECHO OPTION "%0 SUM" FOR COMBINE ALL TO FILE
ECHO OPTION "%0 ARP" FOR ADD ARP - IP LIST
ECHO PARAMETER "SET SUBNET=X" FOR SUBNET
ECHO.
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  As Math noted, your answer isn't terribly useful without some context.  Please edit your answer to add a description of what it does.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
if not "%1"=="am_admin" (powershell start -verb runas '%0' am_admin & exit /b)
arp -d
setlocal
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in (`ipconfig ^| findstr /i "192"`) do (
for /f delims^=^:^ tokens^=2 %%b in ('echo %%a') do (
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=." %%c in ("%%b") do (
set _o1=%%c
set _o2=%%d
set _o3=%%e
set _o4=%%f
set _3octet=!_o1:~1!.!_o2!.!_o3!.
for /L %%a in (1,1,254) do start /min ping /n 1 /l 1 !_3octet!%%a
)))
endlocal
```

After you run the batch file, type this command

```
arp -a
```

**All devices connected to the network will be displayed**

Answer (score -1):

```
for /l %%a in (254, -1, 1) do ( 
    for /l %%b in (1, 1, 254) do (
        for %%c in (20, 168) do (
            for %%e in (172, 192) do (
                ping /n 1 %%e.%%c.%%b.%%a>>ping.txt
            )
        )
    )
)
pause>nul
```

Comment: While the answer address OP's question, it's advisable to include description and context regarding posted code. Otherwise, is like a subject without pronoun in a sentence. Upvoted.